# GCP Dataflow: using Zonal SSD with unknown zone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Currently, we set `region` for our batch and stream Dataflow jobs, eg. `europe-west1`.
When using HDD this is all nice.

But now I would like to test the pipelines with SSD, and according to [worker-level-options](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/pipeline-options#worker-level_options), I can do it but I have to provide the Zone ex-ante.

Is it possible to use zonal SSD PD without specifying the zone, i.e. to use the zone of the workers (automatically)?

Note: I am aware that you can actually set the worker's zone, but I would like to avoid that and let them choose what is best within the region automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Dataflow has options to [auto-]select the zone for SSD other than the [worker_disk_type](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs#disk) option.

Additionally, to improve the performance of your job (see this [common error](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#tsg-rpc-timeout)), you may switch to [Dataflow Shuffle](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-cloud-dataflow-shuffle-for-up-to-5x-performance-improvement-in-data-analytic-pipelines) (should be turned on by default for all batch jobs) or [streaming engine](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/introducing-cloud-dataflows-new-streaming-engine) instead of using the appliance mode to minimize the local disk usage.

Comment: thanks a lot for the links! We are currently already on streaming engine and it works really well - the SSD option just sounded like a tweak to boost performance even more, for relatilvely little extra spending, so we wanted to give it a shot. But the Dataflow Shuffle idea is very promising. Our main focus has been with Stream for a while, but we definitely should give shuffle a shot. Thanks again (will keep the Q open for a bit longer)

Comment: I guess it's about time I accept it. Thanks again (don't know how to add the chinese handle, sorry :-) )